# Extracting multiple lines of text between delimiters from a single cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In Google Sheets or Excel, I would like to extract multiple lines of text between the delimiters `x/` and `/` using a single formula.

**INPUT:**

```
x/Apple Juice/,Banana,Grape,x/Pear Juice/,Cherry,Orange,Blueberry
```

**OUTPUT expected:**

```
Apple Juice, Pear Juice
```

The input line of text may be longer or shorter and the position and instances of "x/text/" can vary.

Comment: Because they are within the delimiter "/" or "x/text/". That is the questions, I would like all text between "x/" and "/" returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, ","), "x/(.*)/"))))
```

[image: 0]